# how to get Multiple values in views page

Tags: php, mysql

Actually, cities are stored multiple values(with ids)

**Example**

(3,5)chennai,bangalore in one table.

How to get city names with the separated comma in views page.

**controller code**

```
    $data['jobCityName'] =explode(',',$viewData['jobCity']);

    for($i= 0; $i < sizeof($data['jobCityName']); $i++) {

    $jobMultipleCity= $data['jobCityName'][$i];

    $data['jobCityNames']=$this->hrm_model->getCitybyId($jobMultipleCity);

    $data['jobCity']=$data['jobCityNames']['cityName'];
```

**views Page Code**

```
<?php echo $jobcity; ?>
```

present printed only one city name.

how to display cities in views page like(hyderabad,chennai,bangalore)

Comment: You can do this in the `SELECT` query by `GROUP_CONCAT`. Show me the query and data structure of both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `foreach` for iteration. Also you are overwriting previous value at `$data['jobCity']=$data['jobCityNames']['cityName'];`

like

```
$data['jobCityName'] =explode(',',$viewData['jobCity']);
foreach($data['jobCityName'] as $cityid) {        
    $data['jobCityNames']=$this->hrm_model->getCitybyId($cityid);
    $data['jobCity'].=$data['jobCityNames']['cityName'];
}
```

Also it's recommended to use `count` instead of `sizeof`

Comment: In controller display all cities,but ion views page display only one city name.Please solve this issue

Comment: Thank u Karan ,displaying cities but show error occuring in contorller,how to solve error
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: jobCity